# Piecing together a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've asked a couple of JavaScript regular expression questions over the last few days as I try to piece together a larger regular expression but I am still having some trouble so I am going to ask about the entire problem, which is probably what I should have done in the first place.

Essentially, what I need is a regular expression that will match all of the following:

1. An empty string.
2. A string that contains at least one alpha-numeric character but does not start with a +1.
3. A string that starts with +1 and has at least 1 more alpha-numeric character.

So some examples are as follows:

```
"" = true
"+" = false
"+abc" = true
"abc" = true
"+1" = false
"+12" = true
"+2" = true
```

Comment: Aren't point 2 and 4 pretty much the opposites, thus basically equalling each other out?

Comment: Your examples contradict your problem statement. `+abc` satisfies possibility 4, a string that starts with + and has at least 1 more alphanumeric character. But you have said that this example should be false (not a match).

Comment: Sorry, that's correct I updated #3 "+abc", it should be true.

Comment: The string `"@1"` satisfies possibility 2, a string that contains at least one alphanumeric character but does not start with a "+". Do you intend `"@1"` to match?

Comment: Why does `+1` not match? It satisfies #4.

Comment: @Regexident you are correct, I was over thinking this a bit and have updated the requirements.  #4 is now gone.  It is actually +1 that should not match by itself.

Comment: @FailedDev `"+abc"` satisfies possibility 2. It is a string that contains at least one alphanumeric character but does not start with `+1`.

Comment: @FailedDev "+abc" is fine because it contains at least one alpha-num.  My original requirements were not thought out well-enough.

Comment: @MetaEd, "@1" would be true as per #2.  It contains 1 alpha-numeric '1' and the @ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your stated requirements as amended, you want to match only:

- An empty string, `^$`
- A string that contains at least one alpha-numeric character but does not start with a +1, `^(?!\+1).*[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- A string that starts with +1 and has at least 1 more alpha-numeric character, `^\+1.*[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Put together, that is:

```
^$|^(?!\+1).*[a-zA-Z0-9]|^\+1.*[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Or, if you like:

```
^($|(?!\+1).*[a-zA-Z0-9]|\+1.*[a-zA-Z0-9])
```

Comment: This answer lost something in the copy and paste. I should have a correction out momentarily.

Comment: I'm not sure if the conditionals work in JavaScript but this seems to just be matching everything.

Comment: After editing, this now seems to work when I copy and test it.

Comment: This pattern is is wrong. `+1 1` will also produce a successful match.

Comment: The pattern `+1 1` satisfies possibility 3, "a string that starts with +1 and has at least 1 more alphanumeric character". Possibility 3 does not stipulate that the +1 and the additional character are adjacent within the string.

Comment: @MetaEd that is correct.  Btw, the expression is working great.

Answer (score 1):

`^(?:\+1[a-zA-Z0-9]+|(?!\+1).*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*)?$`

**Explanation:**

The regex is separated in two cases: `( CASE1 | CASE2 )`

**First case:** `\+1[a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches every text that starts with `+1` and is followed by one or more alphanumeric char (`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` stands for *pick one or more chars that are either from **a** to **z**, from **A** to **Z** or from **0** to **9***)

**Second case:** `(?!\+1).*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*` matches every text that does NOT start with `+1` (`(?!\+1)`), and is followed by as many characters you want as long as it contains at least one alphanumeric char (`.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*` stands for *pick 0 or more of whatever char you want, plus the regex explained above, plus 0 or more of whatever char again*)

These two cases respectively match your rules **#3** and **#2**.

The rule **#1** is taken care of by the `?` at the end of the whole expression, meaning all of that is optional, therefore it can also be an empty string.

**Please note some things such as:**

- `(?:something)` is used to match a string, but not capture it.
- `(?!something)` is used to make sure it doesnt match a string
- `\` is used to escape special characters like `+` when you want them to stand as regular characters
- `+` is used to say *one or more of the preceding item*
- `*` is used to say *zero or more of the preceding item*

Hope i helped!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your most updated requirements:

1. An empty string.
2. A string that contains at least one alpha-numeric character but does not start with a +1.
3. A string that starts with +1 and has at least 1 more alpha-numeric character.

Here is what I'd use:

```
/^([]|(\+1)?.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*)$/
```

In plan english, that regex says to look for a string that is:

1. Empty, or
2. Has an alphanumberic character (and optionally starts with `+1` as well)

Comment: Ehrr.. `.*` also matches non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: The OP doesn't say non-alphanumerics aren't allowed, (s)he just says "contains at least one alphanumeric".

Comment: @ean5533 This matches "+1" but should not unless there is at least one more alpha numeric.

Comment: Non-alpha numerics are allowed and this is very close.

Answer (score 0):

```
//var re = /(^$)/;  //Matches empty
//var re = /(^[a-z0-9]+)/;  //matches only string no plus
//var re = /(^\+([0a-z2-9])([a-z0-9].*)?)/;  //Matches the + [not one] requirement


//Joined together with | for or
//Might be simplified more, but this works ;)
var re = /(^([a-z0-9]+.*|[a-z0-9]+.*|\+1[a-z0-9]+.*|\+([0a-z2-9])([a-z0-9].*)?)?$)/i;

function testIt( str, expected ) {    
    if( !!re.exec( str ) === expected ) {
        console.info(str + "\tpassed" );
    } else{
        console.error(str + "\tfailed" );
    }
}

testIt("", true);
testIt("+", false);
testIt("+abc", true);
testIt("abc", true);
testIt("+1", false);
testIt("+12", true);
testIt("+12_", true);
testIt("+2", true);
testIt("+2c", true);
testIt("+2_", false);
testIt("+007", true);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxvYW/3/)

Comment: `+007` is not matched by this big pattern.

Comment: @epascarello This is close but it doesn't allow extra non-alpha numeric characters.

Comment: @epascarello For example +12_ should be true.

Comment: If only your original requirements said that. ;)

Comment: The requirements do say that, epascarello.

Comment: @epascarello, sorry I guess I should have been more clear that non-alpha numeric characters are allowed so long as the other requirements are met.

Answer (score 0):

```
A string that contains at least one alpha-numeric character but does not start with a +1.  
A string that starts with +1 and has at least 1 more alpha-numeric character.
```

Let's rephrase this a little bit :

**A string that has at least one alpha-numeric character** but does not start with a +1.
A string that starts with +1 and has **at least** *1* **more alpha-numeric character.**

Try again :

but does not start with a +1  | **A string that has at least one alpha-numeric character** A string that starts with +1  | and has **at least** *1* **more alpha-numeric character.**

So what does this let us too?

Nothing. You just wanna match an empty string. I mean really ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at here.  Yes, I would like to match the empty string.  This is going to work in conjunction with some validation and the field will not be required hence the empty string is allowed.